# How to convert number to an int8, int16, int32, uint8, uint16, or uint32

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript

The number variable in TypeScript is floating point. However, there are times when it is necessary to confine the variable to a specific size or type similar to what is available in other languages. For example, the types of int8, int16, int32, uint8, uint16, and uint32. The method that I have implemented converts the number to an unsigned integer and performs a bitwise 'AND' upon the bits needed. Depending if desired type is signed, it will perform a bitwise 'OR'. If there is an error, a better way, or more efficient method, please post.

```js
export class CONVERT
{
   static NumberToUint32(x:number):number 
   {
      return x >>> 0;
   }
   static NumberToUint16(x:number):number 
   {
      return this.NumberToUint32(x) & 0xFFFF;
   }
   static NumberToUint8(x:number):number 
   {
      return this.NumberToUint32(x) & 0xFF;
   }

   static NumberToInt32(x:number): number
   {
      return x >> 0;
   }
   static NumberToInt16(x:number): number
   {
      let r: number = 0; 
      let n = this.NumberToUint16(x);
      if(n & 0x8000)
         r =  0xFFFF8000|(n&0x7FFF);
      else 
         r = n;         
      return(r);      
   }
   static NumberToInt8(x:number): number
   {      
      let r: number = 0; 
      let n = this.NumberToUint8(x);
      if(n & 0x80)
         r =  0xFFFFFF80|(n&0x7F); 
      else 
         r = n;     
      return(r);      
   }      

   static StrToNumber(val: string, defaultVal:number = 0): number
   {        
      let result:number = defaultVal;      
      if(val == null) 
         return result;            
      if(val.length == 0) 
         return result;      
      val = val.trim();
      if(val.length == 0) 
         return(result);
      let sign:number = 1;     
      //
      // . obtain sign from string, and place result in "sign" local varible. The Sign naturally defaults to positive
      //     1 for positive, -1 for negative.
      // . remove sign character from val. 
      //      Note, before the function returns, the result is multiplied by the sign local variable to reflect the sign.
      // . error check for multiple sign characters
      // . error check to make sure sign character is at the head or tail of the string
      //              
      {  
         let positiveSignIndex = val.indexOf('+');
         let negativeSignIndex = val.indexOf('-');
         let nTailIndex = val.length-1;
         //
         // make sure both negative and positive signs are not in the string
         //
         if( (positiveSignIndex != -1) && (negativeSignIndex != -1) ) 
             return result;
         //
         // handle postive sign
         //
         if (positiveSignIndex != -1)
         {
            //
            // make sure there is only one sign character
            //
            if( (positiveSignIndex != val.lastIndexOf('+')) )
             return result;     
             //
             // make sure the sign is at the head or tail
             //
             if( (positiveSignIndex > 0) && (positiveSignIndex < nTailIndex )  )
                 return result;
             //
             // remove sign from string
             //
             val = val.replace("+","").trim();                 
         }    
         //
         // handle negative sign
         //
         if (negativeSignIndex != -1)
         {
            //
            // make sure there is only one sign character
            //
            if( (negativeSignIndex != val.lastIndexOf('-')) )
             return result;     
             //
             // make sure the sign is at the head or tail
             //
             if( (negativeSignIndex > 0) && (negativeSignIndex < nTailIndex )  )
                 return result;
             //
             // remove sign from string
             //
             val = val.replace("-","").trim();  
             sign = -1;                 
         }               
         //
         // make sure text length is greater than 0
         //       
         if(val.length == 0) 
            return result;                             
      }   
      //
      // convert string to a number
      //
      var r = +(<any>val);
      //
      // apply sign if no errors
      //
      if( (r != null) && (!isNaN(r)) )
      {          
         result = r*sign;         
      }
      return(result);    
   }
}
```

Comment: You should post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't have numeric types more specific than `bigint` or `number` because JavaScript itself doesn't and it would be very difficult to enforce that natively in a type system based on JavaScript. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4639 covers that in more detail.

If you still very much want to enforce specific numeric types, your best bet would be a *"branded type"*, such as what https://github.com/kourge/ts-brand provides. Branded numeric types boil down to telling the type system that some type alias refers to `number` *and* also some "brand" property that never actually exists:

```
type Int32 = number & { __brand: "int32" };
```

To turn a value into a branded type, you'd typically use an `as` assertion or type predicate:

```
const zeroAsInt32 = 0 as Int32;
```

The value of branded types is that TypeScript won't let you assign any old `number`-typed value to something that's type `Int32`. You can only assign something that's been "branded" as `int32`.